# Typescript type for passing functions and react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm forcing myself to learn Typescript (urrggg). I usually can determine the type to set by examining the return values. However for the following circumstance, its not working.

```
type SomeReactAProps = {
  Type1: ReactElement;
  Type2: Function;
};

const SomeReactA = ({ Type1, Type2 }: SomeReactAProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Type1}
      <Type2 className="wow" />
    </>
  );
};
type SomeReactBProps = {
  className: string;
};
const SomeReactB = (props: SomeReactBProps) => (<div {..props}>Hello World</div>);

const TestingReact = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SomeReactA Type1={<>Hi</>} Type2={SomeReactB} />
    </>
  );
};
```

The code works. Fitting Typescript to it is the problem.

Type1 works as expected with ReactElement. Kind of surprised that JSX.Element didn't have some of the properties that ReactElement had.

Type2 technically works but Typescript complains Function is too generic. I agree but all my other solutions failed. What type should I set Type2 to?

---

Figured it out. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching, I figured it out.

The type should be

```
(props: SomeReactBProps) => ReactElement
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type2` is likely `React.ReactNode`.

Check out this reference guide: https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet#useful-react-prop-type-examples

Comment: Did not work but I figured out the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless Type2 can be any React component, what you probably want is this:

```
  Type2: React.FunctionComponentElement<typeof Type2>
```

It will force `Type2` proerty to be exactly `<Type2>` component

Comment: Did not work but I figured out the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Type2 is a React functional component you can try this:

```
type SomeReactBProps = {
  className: string;
};

type SomeReactAProps = {
  Type1: ReactElement;
  Type2: React.FC<SomeReactBProps>;
};
```

Comment: Did not work but I figured out the solution. Thanks!